# how to documents variables inside functions via phpDoc

Tags: php, phpdoc

I am using [PHPDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) standards for commenting  PHP(laravel) code and [ApiGen](http://www.apigen.org/) to generate an API Documentation.

I know that there are many Tags that can be used to present information.

define() statements, functions, classes, class methods, and class vars, include() statements, and global variables can all be documented.

But now I want to document variables that are in a function.
for example suppose I have a function like this :

```
         /**
         * @param Request $request
         * @param         $course_id
         * @param         $lesson_id
         * @param Content $content
         *
         * @return array
         *
         */
        public function SaveOnePageTest (Request $request, $course_id, $lesson_id, \App\Content $content)
        {
            /**
            *I want to document this variable that how does this and What used to be?
            */

            $doneTest = DoneTest::find($done_test_id);

            /**
            *or this variable 
            */
            $parentQuestions = $doneTest->parent_test->questions;
        }
```

Is there a solution to this case?

Comment: There's no "formalised" approach to this, you simply add whatever comments you want

Comment: use simple comments can not create any information about variables inside functions in final API documentation.

Comment: No it can't, but why should any end user need to know about the internals of a method?

Comment: @Mark Baker, no i do not need that end user to know internal method, I want it for me and my contributors. in fact I do not know other companies use which tools to code maintenance

Comment: As you and the contributors should have direct access to the code, then there's surely no issue with simply commenting the code itself. Tools like PHPDoc and ApiGen are for documenting the end-user interfaces to the class/methods/properties, not internal code values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this kind of documentation tool/syntax have been developed to help people consuming a library/a software API.

Local variables are not accessible to the end user so there is no real need to expose them in the documentation.

While you can document your inner code, there is no standard way to do this using PHPDoc.

**Update :** Note that You can use phpdoc to define the type of a variable in order to get better code completion, but that will not be part of the API documentation :

```
/** @var SomeType $someVar */
$someVar = $this->doSomething();
```

Comment: However, are not there any ways to document local variables? Why so I am working on large project and I want to create a documentation for that to remember that classes , variables , methods , ... what do ?

Comment: just use regular comment for local variables, if someone needs to interact with local variable he will need to open the code whatever happen...